# Issue with post request using requests Python lib and dict of dicts

Tags: python, json, simplejson, python-requests

I'm new with Python and I need to build a Python library that connect to our API service sending some json data, everything works fine but one thing, I need to send some dict of dicts doing a POST request:

```
    def create_project(self, project):
        print project
        params = simplejson.dumps(project)
        print params
        req = requests.post(self.url+'/projects/addSpeedy.json',
            data=params, 
            auth=HTTPBasicAuth(self.api_id, self.api_key),verify=False)
        data = simplejson.loads(req.text)
        return data
```

the project param I'm passing to that function contains the following structure:

```
    script = {
        'part001': 'HI',
        'part002': 'WORLD'
    }
    project = {
        'title': 'Project posted from Python Carrot',
        'script': script,
        'remarks': "I want the voice be similar to Bugs Bunny.",
        'test': '1'
    }
```

However when doing the request the API tells me the 'title' field which is required is missing, however when printing the data in the function everything seems fine, the dict json encode was something I saw in the requests site for this cases:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

I've tried other ways with mixed results it doesnt work the way it should, also the problem its not the API since we have libraries in other languages and it works fine.

Comment: is this python 2.x using urllib2?  don't you have to send the request before you get a response?  Also, you probably want to make sure you include the content type header.  Perhaps: req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

Comment: when you add the '.json' the API detects it has to answer the request in json, also I have other post request functions that work fine, the problem with the request is when I'm using a dict of dicts. Also the API is answering with an error. Its not a connection issue is the data I'm sending.

Comment: Have you considered using a library such as https://github.com/VoiceBunny/python-carrot ?

Comment: Korylprince that's the library I'm extending :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to guess, what's going wrong without further details about your http client and the server API. My first try debugging this would be to grab [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and check, if your generated requests are identical to the ones generated with the implementation of your other clients with the following questions to answer:

- Are some headers different?
- Content-Length and Content-Type specified correctly?
- Did the authentication succeed or is the response with the missing title used quite generically?

Comment: As I told to monkut before, the problem its not the connection, its the data I'm sending, I've used requests for other requests and it works correctly, like in this case:



    `def quote(self, params):
     req = requests.post(self.url+'/projects/quote.json', 
         params,
         auth=HTTPBasicAuth(self.api_id, self.api_key),verify=False)
     data = simplejson.loads(req.text)
     return data`

The API I'm trying to connect is the VoiceBunny API https://voicebunny.com/developers/projects/addSpeedy

Comment: Well, even then I'd start debugging with comparing the finally transmitted data. Have you already looked at the plain body of your request and checked, that it's valid json? Maybe some brackets around your data are lacking? Does your API maybe only understand specific quotations of the fieldnames, " instead of ', and simplejson would use the wrong one? Watching the actual network traffic will show you any of these slight differences instantly.

Comment: Thanks! I tried another approach before sending the script argument as an str but I was using ' not " in my json str, it worked!
`script = '{"part001": "HI", "part002": "WORLD", "part003": "LOL"}'`

Comment: Another thing to point out, its that the data was lost after I debugged what the API was receiving in the request. I have no idea why, since I was using the suggested approach of the requests doc.

Comment: I just had a quick look in the [json specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). It only mentions these kind of quotation marks `"`, so it's ok if your server doesn't understand the other ones, but loosing data is indeed weird.